# Navigation Drawer not visible

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am working on an app right now, the main component is to display **pdf**'s. I have used the **plugpdf library** for this, with this code in the mainactivity:

```
try{
    // Initialize PlugPDF with a license key.
    PlugPDF.init(getApplicationContext(),
            "my license key here, censored for obvious reasons");
} catch (PlugPDFException.InvalidLicense ex) {
    Log.e("PlugPDF", "error ", ex);
    // Handle invalid license exceptions.
}


SimpleDocumentReader v = SimpleReaderFactory.createSimpleViewer(this, null);
v.openUrl(link, "123456");
```

So basically, I am opening an activity in the mainactivity. 
[Here's how it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfoVF.png)

The problem with this is, that the simpledocumentreader (the activity for the pdf viewer), is "on top" of the main activity, that means, if I click on the Navigation Drawer icon, I won't see anything.

[Here's how it is *supposed* to look like. (The pdf should be still visible in the background)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvgWh.png)

So, basically I somehow need to achieve putting the navigation drawer "on top" of the SimpleDocumentReader. Strangely, I create the pdf reader view first, and then the navigation drawer fragment, and still, the pdf appears on top of the navigation drawer.
So, the question is, *how*?

Comment: Is your DrawerLayout correct? Do you have the drawer View listed last?

Comment: Yes, first, I call the pdf activity, then the drawer fragment with view etc. I tried changing the order of the code pieces (put the pdf behind the drawer, before), but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: No, I mean in the layout xml.

Comment: Oh, for that, there's this thing: Because the plugpdf is an library, the reader has its own layout so it isn't even mentioned in the main activity layout, nor the navigation drawer layout. I just call the view in the mainactivity.

Comment: Well, it's hard to be certain, since their website is worthless, but it would seem that the reader is just another Activity, in which case you can't display your drawer over it.

Comment: Yes, it's opening the SimpleReaderControlView. And there's no workaround to that? Like, for example, putting the navigation drawer somehow in that activity, or, somehow, moving the activity to the back?

Comment: If it is an Activity, no, you can't do either of those things. However, if the library provides some way to get a reader View object, you'd put that in the content layout inside your DrawerLayout. I'm not sure if it does; the site isn't terribly informative.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it creates an activity, and you can't do pretty much anything to it. It also seems that you can't convert the activity to a fragment. Any ideas for a good pdf reader plugin for free/ free for non-commercial use?